# Jquery push to specific object after JSON call

Tags: jquery, json

I was wondering how you can push a new value to an existing array after a second JSON call.
So what I mean is this:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
  var brandsArr = []
  $.each(data.collection.brands, function(index, brand){
     brandsArr.push({'title': brand_title, 'url': brand_url, 'image': 'This one I don't have' }) 
     
     // To get the brand image I need to make a second JSON call
     $.getJSON(brand_url, function(data){
        brandsArr.splice(2, 0, imageIdToUrl(data.collection.image, '170x170x2'))
     });

   });  
 });
```

As a result I have this:
​

```
{ title: "Naish", url: "/brands/naish", image: "" }
{ title: "Cabrinha", url: "/brands/cabrinha", image: "" }
​{ title: "Duotone", url: "/brands/duotone", image: "" }
{ title: "Brunotti", url: "/brands/brunotti", image: "" }
```

So after the first call I can push the title + url to an array. To get the image I need a second call.
I tried things like `splice` etc. However I understand that I need somekind of index to push the image to the correct object. Right now it just pushes the imnage into the array and not to the correct object, like so:
​

```
{ title: "Naish", url: "/brands/naish", image: "" }
{ title: "Cabrinha", url: "/brands/cabrinha", image: "" }
​{ title: "Duotone", url: "/brands/duotone", image: "" }
{ title: "Brunotti", url: "/brands/brunotti", image: "" }
{"link-to-brand-image/image.jpg"}
{"link-to-brand-image/image.jpg"}
{"link-to-brand-image/image.jpg"}
{"link-to-brand-image/image.jpg"}
```

How can I push that corresponding image to the correct object?

Comment: Don't push to the array until the second request completes giving you all the data needed for your object

Comment: @charlietfl: Ohh man! How dumb can someone be xD... Thx for the insight haha